# SSDT with DB project reference throwing strange compile error

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a solution with 2 SSDT database projects, one referencing the other. In one of the stored procedures I have a simple update statement that looks something like the following:

```
update [$(otherDb)]..OtherTable set TheField = @value where OtherTable.Id = @id
```

I have many stored procedures that do this very same operation on other tables, this stored procedure has been working for many months, and intellisense even is even able to display all of the columns of the the table. Even still I get an error saying

```
SQ71561: Procedure [dbo].[MyProcedure] has an unresolved reference to object [$(otherDb)].[dbo].[OtherTable].[TheField]
```

Any body have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the DBML files and rebuilding the projects did it

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the underline view does not use SELECT *
2. Remove the Reference and Add the database reference again,select the check button Suppress Warning....
3. Rebuild the project- that should solve it

Answer (score 0):

This is Jony Lalwani.

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and it has the SSDT version 15.1. I checked the usage of variable [$(DATABASE)] in scripts and below are the observations-

1-    Stored Procedure, Table Valued Functions & Scalar Functions will only throw unresolved reference warning if you use DB.dbo.Table instead of [$(DB)].dbo.Table. Therefore even if we don’t use the variable the build is successful in these scripts.
2-    By design Inline Functions & Views will throw unresolved reference error if we use DB.dbo.Table instead of [$(DB)].dbo.Table. Therefore in these scripts variable references are required.

The above two points are also valid for Visual studio 2013 SSDT (12.0) and it is working same way there as well. However VS 2013 SSDT sometime throws multiple error of unresolved reference also in Stored procedure when we import or update schema from SQL database. This is due to bugs in 2013 SSDT.